# Computing the FOLLOW sets

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ll-grammar

My task is to calculate FIRST and FOLLOW sets for the following grammar:

```
P ::= S CS .
S ::= ( int , int )
CS ::= C CS | epsilon
C ::= left int | right int | low C
```

I got the following first sets:

```
FIRST(S) = {'('}
FIRST(C) = {left,right,low}
FIRST(CS) = {left,right,low,epsilon}
FIRST(P) = FIRST(S) = {'('}
```

For the following sets I calculated:

```
FOLLOW(P) = $ (or empty)
FOLLOW(C) = {left,right,low,'.'}
FOLLOW(CS) = {'.'}
FOLLOW(S) = {left,right,low}
```

I tried out my solution using first and follow sets generator and what I got with FOLLOW(S) was: `FOLLOW(S) = {'.', left, right, low}`. Is generator's solution correct and why? I calculated my solution using formula: `FOLLOW(S) = FIRST({left,right,low} concat FOLLOW(P)) = {left, right, low}`. Can someone please explain me why my/ generator's solution is not correct and check whether I got everything else right? I also want to know why I don't have `int` in any first or follow set and if this will be okay with building parser later anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute FOLLOW sets you have to be careful with​ empty productions.

In this case, `CS` has an empty production, which means that `S` might be followed by a `.` in `P →  S CS .`. Similarly, the `C` in `C CS` might be at the end of the production, so `C` could also be followed by a `.`

`int` can only appear after a `left` or `right` token. It can never appear at the beginning of a nom-terminal nor immediately following a non-terminal. So it is entirely expected that it not be in any FIRST or FOLLOW set.

Comment: Thank you :) I think I fully understand now how FIRST and FOLLOW sets work. I only have one more question. According to those rules how to determine FOLLOW sets I cannot see any rule that would include a '.' into my FOLLOW(S) set... Do I just have to be careful about empty productions like this or there actually is a rule that determines this?

Comment: It's the rule I specify in the second paragraph of my answer,  `P → S CS .` . If CS is empty, the dot immediately follows the S. Or maybe I don't understand what you mean. The FOLLOW set of a nonterminal is the set of tokens which can come me next next n the input after an instance of that nonterminal.